# Xamarin - Updating The App Without App Store

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

Is there a technical limitation why Xamarin does not support updating the application without publishing to the app store? Javascript cross-platform mobile development frameworks like React Native or Cordova can do this.

Comment: Xamarin produces a "native" app, same as a Swift/Obj-based iOS app or a Java-based Android app. In a hybrid app you have the option to update the **content** of the app which are html/javascript/media/... resources. You can do the exact same thing with any "native" app, including Xamarin, if you write a hybrid app and provide a mechanism to download and cache the updated resources for the embedded browser

Comment: React Native also produces a native app, it is not hybrid. It just happens to use JS instead of C#.

Comment: `React Native` is a native **shell** that uses `JavaScriptCore` to execute `JavaScript`. Your program logic is running on a javascript thread communicating to "native" UI components (and frameworks) that were instantiated by JavaScript. While there are direct comparisons to Xamarin's Mono VM and Android's Art/Dalvik VM architecture to be made, the end result leans more towards a hybrid style app then a fully native app (iOS Swift/ObjC or Android C/C++ NDK). `Xamarin.iOS` compiles to LLVM bitcode but has an embedded .NET/CIL VM, so less "native", but more "native" then React Native....

Comment: `Xamarin.Android` is a weird bird, as it has two VMs, the .NET/CIL VM and a full bridge to the Android Java VM. The end app that `Xamarin.Android` produces is an Android NDK (C-based) app that includes the Mono VM and CIL-based assemblies (AOT'd or not). So it is more comparable to React Native... React Native has really complete guide on describing how its use of JavaScript is based on achieving a 60 fps, how threading works, etc... in the end it is not "native", but I would not call `Xamarin.Android` end result native either, if they re-enable AOT/LLVM in the future, it will be *more* native

Answer (score 4):

You are comparing Apples to Oranges in a sense. When it comes down to Native Development, Xamarin is a framework that allows you to do Native Development via Wrappers: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/getting_started/introduction_to_mobile_development/#How_Does_Xamarin_Work

Because of this, you would do the same workflow as if you were pushing an update to your Native Android/iOS application(Programmed in Java/Obj-C respectfully).

Whereas on the other side with frameworks like React/Cordova, they have mechanisms to `inject` content via pulling from a server-side service. This is explained pretty clearly in a third party cordova project that does this very thing:

https://github.com/markmarijnissen/cordova-app-loader

However if you made a `local` Cordova application that had no connection to a server-side service and you needed to update it, you would most likely have to follow the same procedure of uploading the new `.ipa` / `.apk` with the new assets/code/etc as it would be a packaged stand-alone app.

Comment: React Native also produces a native app, it is not hybrid. It just happens to use JS instead of C#.

Comment: Sure. But then that falls directly under the same category of pushing updates via the appstore rather than pushing content to your server side service. Just like @SushiHangover mentioned earlier, you could technically do this in any framework as `WebView` controls are very dynamic to the content they consume.

Comment: But you could do the same thing that Cordova plugin I mentioned earlier can do in `React` or just about any framework honestly. At the end of the day we might choose one option over the other for our business needs. (i.e. Getting app updates immediately to users or having a native experience)

Answer (score 0):

That's because all the code is in js files that can be downloaded an replaced out side of the ARM binary. Xamarin's code is the binary. Also, if your code is in the App Store, you *should* be updating through the store. This is less of a limitation of Xamarin (since you can't do this with native obj-c apps either) and more of a "pro" for the js apps.

As a side note, if you go with Enterprise deployment instead of App Store, you can update whenever you want (because you completely control the deployment mechanism).